# named parameter not passing correctly in jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc, java-7

I'm calling procedure with named parameter using JDBC CallableStatement.

Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE VIST_COMP(I_STUDY IN VARCHAR2, I_STARTDATE IN VARCHAR2, I_ENDDATE IN VARCHAR2, I_EMPLOYEE IN VARCHAR2, I_EMPLOYEE_OPTIONAL IN NUMBER, I_SPONSOR IN VARCHAR2, I_SPONSOR_OPTIONAL IN NUMBER, p_rc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
o_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
sqlqry clob;
BEGIN
  //procedure code 
END VIST_COMP;
```

Java Code:

```
String runSP = "call VIST_COMP(:protocols,:alertStartDate,:alertEndDate,:employee,:employeeOptional,:sponsor,:sponsorOptional, :out_cursor)";         
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:389/oracle", "username", "password");
CallableStatement callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(runSP)) {
   callableStatement.setString("protocols","12345");
   callableStatement.setString("alertStartDate", "03-Apr-2019");
   callableStatement.setString("alertEndDate", "03-Jun-2019");
   callableStatement.setString("employee",null);
   callableStatement.setInt("employeeOptional",1);
   callableStatement.setString("sponsor", "abc");
   callableStatement.setInt("sponsorOptional",0);

   callableStatement.registerOutParameter("out_cursor", OracleTypes.CURSOR);

   // run it
   callableStatement.execute();
   ResultSet rset = (ResultSet)   callableStatement.getObject("out_cursor");

   while(rset.next()) {
     System.out.println(rset.getString("LABEL_VALUE"));
   }
}catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above code is working well and i recieved ResultSet also. But the issue is if i change set parameter order it didn't working. For example if i set `sponsor` above date's like below giving error.

```
callableStatement.setString("protocols","12345");
callableStatement.setString("alertStartDate", "03-Apr-2019");
callableStatement.setString("sponsor", "abc");
callableStatement.setString("alertEndDate", "03-Jun-2019");
callableStatement.setString("employee",null);
callableStatement.setInt("employeeOptional",1);
callableStatement.setInt("sponsorOptional",0);
```

DB error is

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected
>
> ORA-06512: at "VIST_COMP", line 266

Using Build path Java 1.7( installed JDK 1.8), Oracle 12c, Ojdbc6.jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use named parameters to call Oracle stored procedures, you can consider using [morejdbc](https://github.com/seregamorph/morejdbc). Your call will look like this:

```java
import static org.morejdbc.NamedJdbcCall.call;
import org.morejdbc.*;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

// I do not know the structure of returned ref_cursor, so let it be a single column of varchar
RowMapper<String> mapper = (rs, rowNum) -> rs.getString("value");
Out<List<String>> resultOut = Out.of(OracleSqlTypes.cursor(mapper));
jdbcTemplate.execute(call("VIST_COMP")
    .in("protocols", "12345") // note: argument name is Oracle PL/SQL argument name
    .in("alert_start_date", "03-Apr-2019")
    .in("alert_end_date", "03-Jun-2019")
    .in("employee", null)
    .in("employeeOptional", 1)
    .in("sponsor", "abc")
    .in("sponsorOptional", 0),
    .out("out_cursor", resultOut));

System.out.println("Result is " + resultOut.get());
```

It requires Java 1.8 and spring, but if your project has another stack you can at least adapt helper classes, if you find it convenient.